# Why can't I set the height of a modal dialog?

Tags: jquery, css, modal-dialog

I had a div:

```
<div id="mydiv" style="height:900px;display:none"></div>
```

And I made a modal dialog call :

```
$("#mydiv").load("./d3present.html").dialog({ 
    width: 600,height:500,draggable: false}); 
  $('#mydiv').dialog('options',"height",900);
```

However,I cann't set the height 900px for my dialog,What is wrong?

```
<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front ui-resizable" style="position: absolute; height: auto; width: 600px; top: 648px; left: 327.5px; display: block;" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-describedby="mydiv" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1"
```

As is seen above,the height is still auto.

And I am using jquery:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Please give me a hand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to remove extra 's':

```
$('#mydiv').dialog('option',"height",900);
```

FYI, load() is async, better seems to be to initialize dialog plugin inside load() method complete callback.

```
$("#mydiv").load("./d3present.html", function () {
    $(this).dialog({
        width: 600,
        /*height: 500,*/ //if height depends of content, you should remove it
        draggable: false
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't realize load() is async.Now it works!